# Set value of input field after retrieving it using an external script (HTML dom refresh ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I want to do**

Get a form using an external script. Prefill and disable some fields. Example:

[image]

**How I do it**

I retrieve a form using an external script(s) :

```
<!-- Lumesse js imports -->
<!--Apply-->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-app/static/apply/release/2-LATEST/apply-preloader-namespaced.js"
    th:src="@{https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-app/static/apply/release/2-LATEST/apply-preloader-namespaced.js}"
    data-lumesse-apply=""
    data-lumesse-apply-config-key="XXX"
    data-lumesse-apply-host="https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com"
    data-lumesse-apply-description-placement="bottom"
    data-lumesse-apply-menu="top"
    data-lumesse-apply-menu-placement="top"
    data-lumesse-apply-repeatable-style="on-demand">        
</script>
<script src="https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-
 app/static/apply/release/2-LATEST/apply-application-form-namespaced.js"
    th:src="@{https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-
app/static/apply/release/2-LATEST/apply-application-form-namespaced.js}">
</script>
<!-- in comment because otherwise conflict with static/vendor/jquery.min.js -->
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"
    th:src="@{https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js}"
    th:integrity="sha" 
th:crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
<script src="https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-
app/static/themes/release/latest/silk/js/main.js"
    th:src="@{https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-
app/static/themes/release/latest/silk/js/main.js}"></script>
```

The code for prefill or disable works fine.:

```
<!-- custom javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {
// fix menu when passed
$('.masthead').visibility({
    once : false,
    onBottomPassed : function() {
        $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade in');
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({'top': '52px'});
    },
    onBottomPassedReverse : function() {
        $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade out');
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css({'top': '75px'});
    }
});
// create sidebar and attach to menu open
$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('attach events', '.toc.item');

window.setTimeout(function(){
    preFillForm();
    },0);
});

function preFillForm(){
    var gegevens = [[${gegevens}]];
    for(var id in gegevens){
        $("#" + id).val(gegevens[id]);
    }
    $("#first_name_1").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#last_name_2").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#e-mail_address_3").attr('disabled','disabled');
}
</script>
```

**The problem**

My fields don't get prefilled .. My guess is because they don't get reloaded or get overwritten ..

**First possible solution**

After many hours I added a setTimeout of 0. This seems to work. Now I discovered that this only works on a page refresh or when the user already visited the site and did a page refresh before ...
So still when a user go to the site for the first time it doesn't work ..

Any help would be much appreciated
Cheers

(PS: setTimeout of more seconds is not the way I want to go ..)

**UPDATED**

My application is a Spring Boot App. Working with Thymeleaf. Also use of Semantic and Jquery in FrontEnd.

Answer (score -1):

Try using sessionStorage or localStorage (sessionStorage seems to be better in this situation).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage